# Norm- Orthogonal Projection $A^{t}A=I_{n}$

Tags: linear-algebra, normed-spaces

Let $A_{m\times n}$ be a matrix such that  $m\geq n$ and $A^{t}A=I_{n}$. It is given that the columns of $A$ are orthonormal. I need to show that the 2-norm of each row of $A$ is $\leq 1$. I have no idea how I should start this problem. Obviously the 2-norm of each column is equal to 1. I was trying to work with $A^{t}$ and prove that the 2-norm of each of its columns (which are rows of $A$) is less than $1$, but I couldn't do it. Anyone can help? Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Observe that $AA^T$ is an orthogonal projection (satisfying $P^2=P^T=P$). It projects to some subspace $U$ of $\ \Bbb R^m$ (playing the space of the rows).

Now, if $e$ is a unit vector in $\Bbb R^m$ with projection $u=AA^Te$, then we have
$$e^TAA^Te \ =\ e^TAA^TAA^Te\ =\ \langle u,u\rangle\ =\ \|u\|^2\ \le\ 1, $$
because $u$ is the orthogonal projection of the unit vector $e$.

The (square of the) row norm of the $i$th row is just $\|A^Te_i\|^2=e_i^TAA^Te_i$ with the $i$th element of the standard basis of $\Bbb R^m$.